# heroku pgbackups:restore: an error occurred and your restore did not finish

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am attempting to restore a local snapshot of a database into a heroku dev instance.

```
heroku pgbackups:restore --app app_name HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AMBER_URL https://www.dropbox.com/etc
```

But I consistently receive the following error

```
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AMBER_URL  <---restore---  db.dump

Retrieving... done
!    An error occurred and your restore did not finish.
```

The database snapshot was captured using the pg_dump string in the heroku docs:

```
PGPASSWORD=pwd pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres db > db.dump
```

and the dump file is in a dropbox share (so available with direct URL access)

Both Heroku and the local database are PG 9.2.

Comment: Have you looked at what the error says in `heroku logs` ?

Comment: Well, there you go. Check the logs, stupid! Thanks man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku logs contain all of the output from pgbackups, which will help track down the issue.

Comment: @Thermech Just type the command `heroku pg:backups:info <backupkey>` where backupkey is the key generated for the current backup.